# What's a good simple test for cDNA library quality?

Tags: pcr, cdna

How do I assess the quality of a cDNA library?

I want to clone CDS copies of genes from a library, but I don't know what's a typical expectation of getting a full length clone even for a shorter gene (~1000 bp).  I know it doesn't have to be composed of full length cDNA for sequencing, but I'd imagine quality of starting materials is important there too.

Are there some common transcripts I can try to obtain from PCR that will tell me how fragmented the sequences are in there?

What's a typical result from a commercial cDNA library - are there any QC tests that are quick to run in the lab?

Comment: From what kind of cells do you have your library? I think the answer heavily depends on that info.

Comment: did you try googling? actin seems to be useful probe target: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3273856

Comment: @poka.nandor interesting - human testis or spleen - does that help?

Comment: quite a lot! At least we know what genes should be expressed, however there are housekeeping genes that expressed in most or all cell types like actin as aandreev suggested.

Comment: Is this library for sequencing? What is your experimental setup?  Did you perform reverse transcription and you want to check how well it went? I deleted my answer as when I tried to work on it it raised more questions on the post.

Comment: You would usually run you library into a Bioanalyzer and check that the fragment distribution looks something like you expect. From there you can look at housekeeping genes to make sure those are present in the library. The expected fragment length distribution largely depends on the kit, the experimental approach and the sample type you are using so it is pretty much impossible to tell you exactly what you should expect with no information on that. Also the library depends on what kind of sequencer you want to use, you don't want the same library for say Sanger sequencing or a MiSeq run.

Comment: I was hoping for something more like this @caligari2005.  how can I tell if the cDNA is fragmented or full length.  I'll change the question.